# How to parse C++ source in Python?

Tags: c++, python, parsing, code-analysis

We want to  parse our huge C++ source tree to gain enough info to feed to another tool to make diagrams of class and object relations, discern the overall organization of things etc.

My best try so far is a Python script that scans all .cpp and .h files, runs regex searches to try to detect class declarations, methods, etc.   We don't need a full-blown analyzer to capture every detail, or some heavy UML diagram generator - there's a lot of detail we'd like to ignore and we're inventing new types of diagrams.  The script sorta works, but by gosh it's true: C++ *is* hard to parse!

So I wonder what tools exist for extracting the info we want from our sources?   I'm not a language expert, and don't want something with a steep learning curve.  Something we low-brow blue-collar programmer grunts can use :P

Python is preferred as one of the standard languages here, but it's not essential.

Comment: C++ is notoriously hard to parse, and you usually need some pretty heavyweight tools to do it (GLR parsers, for example).  I would be very surprised if there was a good approximation of C++ parsing that didn't use some pretty powerful parsers.

Comment: Have you looked into a standard compiler-compiler?  These use a special language (some sort of Extended Backus-Naur Form -- remember college?) to describe the target language.

Comment: Did you consider using GCC-XML ( http://www.gccxml.org ) and then python for the processing of the resulting XML file?

Comment: I have heard it said that there are no more than three complete C++ parsers in the world -- GCC's parser, EDG's parser, and *maybe* Microsoft's parser (Microsoft may or may not be using EDG).  The LLVM folks are working on one but it's not done yet, and you may guess from the above just how much work is involved; also someone (I forget who) here on SO claimed to have one at his company, but I can't assess that claim.  Sadly, none of the above are in Python.  EDG's parser is designed to be easily hooked to a new consumer, but the licensing ain't cheap.

Comment: +1  I like the "maybe" for MS - but maybe they all should be "maybe"?

Comment: One advantage I enjoy is that >90% of the source follows a consistent style.  I can mostly count on semicolons, curlies, etc being in certain places making it easy-ish to classify lines.  This is cheating, of course.  The question is how much better parsing can I get for how much heaviness of tooling.

Comment: @DarenW: that depends heavily on how much your current tool is failing, and why.  If you identify the failures and reasons, then you can understand what level of parsing is required, for example: does it already work with CRTP, do you have failures due to not modelling namespace lookup rules, do you need to know which `#if/#else` branches are followed to get accurate results...?

Comment: @Tony: yes, there are failures, but the nature of this projects is very one-off, in-house and so just hacking in kludges to get around the trouble spots is good enough for us.  I'd have to do something much smarter were I to open source this or let others at work use it.

Comment: @DarenW: well, sounds like you're best sticking with what's working for you already.

Comment: For clarity, I said "maybe" MS not to cast aspersions on MSVC++ but because (as far as I've heard, anyway) nobody who knows will say whether Microsoft wrote their own C++ parser or whether they licensed EDG's parser.

Comment: Why is Python a necessary part of the solution?  Seems like you are just adding restrictions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll simply recommend [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/).

It's a C++ library-based compiler designed with ease of reuse in mind. It notably means that you can use it solely for parsing and generating an Abstract Syntax Tree. It takes care of all the tedious operator overloading resolution, template instantiation and so on.

Clang exports a C-based interface, which is extended with Python Bindings. The interface is normally quite rich, but I haven't use it. Anyway, contributions are welcome if you wish to help extending it.

Comment: I had no idea CLang was in such a state already. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I've tried CLang for compiling the whole thing, but a few obscure lacunae in its parsing kept the build from going too far.  It's worth trying again, though, since I like error messages that make sense.  For just analyzing the source and not building, it just might be the best tool.

Comment: FWIW, the official Clang website spells Clang with a lowercase L.

Comment: @trinithis: yes, it's a typo. I tend to press Shift a tad too long :x Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6):

You could check out GccXML and OpenC++, as well as doxygen.

Comment: OpenC++ is getting rather long in the tooth.

Comment: what does "long in the tooth" mean?

Comment: @tenfour: long in the tooth === Old  (Its because old people have longer gnarlier teeth).

Comment: "Long in the tooth" has to do with horses with receding gums over the years.  (disclaimer: IANAHE = I Am Not A Horse Expert)

Answer (score 3):

Can you run a preprocessing step?  Doxygen parses most C++ syntax and creates xml with all the relationships.  Compilers also create debug databases (typically dwarf format from gcc and codeview format from MSC).

Comment: We use doxygen, but will that mean I have to parse XML to get what I want?

Comment: @DarenW: python has an xml library, doesn't it?  So all the hard work of parsing should be done for you, you just need to use the object model to pull out the details you want.

Answer (score 1):

From what you say of our requirements, Tony's answer of GccXML will probably be the best option. If that doesn't work, you could try to generate an outline of your program with cscope or ctags, and then work your way to the info you want from it's output.

Comment: Ctags with the -x option write info similar to what I'm trying to create.  It's not quite right-on though.  Maybe it can be massaged into what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for tools that can extract information from C++.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is configurable compiler technology for building custom analyzers.  It has a full [C++ Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html) with a preprocesser, full C++ parsing with AST construction (including capture of comments), and full symbol table.   These could be used to extract such structural information, and export it to whatever you want to process it.

EDIT: One of the comments is that there are only 3 full C++ parsers in the world.  I suspect more; surely IBM has one that works.   DMS's C++ front end has been used in anger on large applications in both MS Visual Studio and on GNU C++ source codes, so it might reasonably qualify, too :-}

Answer (score 0):

I've had good experience with PLY:

http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/

But this requires some experience with lex and yacc

Comment: If you want a full C++ parser, you don't want to build it yourself, unless you want to make a career out of it.  Trust me.

Comment: That's not what OP asked.  grabbing the AST from GCC is probably the best, but the OP didnt seem to want full parsing

Comment: If he doesn't use a full parser, his answers won't be accurate.  If he doesn't care if his answers are accurate, maybe a hack will work.  That usually ends up being pretty unsatisfying in the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you can bring yourself to run this analysis using a Windows-platform application, save yourself a lot of time and trouble, and spend $200 on Enterprise Architect by Sparx Systems (I have no affiliation with this company, just a satisfied customer).  (Note: this should not be confused with Microsoft's own "Enterprise Architect" bundle for Visual Studio.)

EA can reverse-engineer a number of languages, including C++, C, Java, and Python, generating some very nice UML class diagrams. (EA comes in a number of different packages, Desktop is the cheapest but you have to by Professional, the 2nd cheapest, to get the code engineering feature included.)  I also like the integration between the generated class diagrams and sequence diagramming, where you can drag a line between object lifelines and a menu of defined methods is presented to you based on the class definition of the target object.   At my former consulting business, we used this tool quite a bit to develop system architectural proposals which we then included as part of our project bid (just copy/paste the diagram into a Word doc).  It wont take long to make back your $200.

Comment: Something that costs money and runs on Windows isn't going to fly here, a hive full of Linux-based physicists.  You have used it mostly for new systems?  Is it good for gaining an understanding of an existing huge code base?

Comment: It is funny how we think that writing a partial solution over the course of weeks is better than spending $200 - usually that's considered pointy-haired boss thinking. Yes, I have used it for getting the big picture of an existing code base, you really just point it at the directory containing the code, choose the language and file extensions, and click "Go". Sure, it can generate some pretty complicated diagrams, but it will break up the diagrams according to your directory and/or package structure, and you can simplify the diagrams after the fact.