# Python - How to split a string by non alpha characters

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I'm trying to use python to parse lines of c++ source code. The only thing I am interested in is include directives.

```
    #include "header.hpp"
```

I want it to be flexible and still work with poor coding styles like:

```
          #   include"header.hpp"
```

I have gotten to the point where I can read lines and trim whitespace before and after the #. However I still need to find out what directive it is by reading the string until a non-alpha character is encountered regardless of weather it is a space, quote, tab or angled bracket.

So basically my question is: How can I split a string starting with alphas until a non alpha is encountered?

I think I might be able to do this with regex, but I have not found anything in the documentation that looks like what I want.

Also if anyone has advice on how I would get the file name inside the quotes or angled brackets that would be a plus.

Comment: do you want to split or retrieve the "header.hpp" part?   can you give example output?

Comment: Include an example string and the expected result please.

Comment: if the directive is anything other then include it doesn't matter and I will skip to the next line, but if it is an include directive I will need the "header.hpp" part.

Comment: example string: "#include "header.hpp""     desired output if the directive is include: "header.hpp" (or ""header.hpp"")

Comment: Plain python, or are library suggestions allowed?

Comment: library suggestions are allowed ;)

Comment: "I will skip to the next line": do you think it is relevant with C++ syntax?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte The only thing this script does is gather the dependencies of a C++ source files (included header files). So the rest of C++'s syntax doesn't really matter as long as all include directives are found.

Comment: You can find several suggestions in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881377/how-to-parse-c-source-in-python

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do that with a regex. However, you can also use a simple `while` loop.

```
def splitnonalpha(s):
   pos = 1
   while pos < len(s) and s[pos].isalpha():
      pos+=1
   return (s[:pos], s[pos:])
```

Test:

```
>>> splitnonalpha('#include"blah.hpp"')
('#include', '"blah.hpp"')
```

Comment: I'm picking this answer because  a) it means I don't have to deal with regex and  b) other solutions were failing with other preprocessor directives like define and this one wasn't

Comment: @nickeb96 - I recommend you find a real C parser. This (was the worst)  as with all the other answers can't come close.

Comment: @sln I will probably look at C parsers later on, but since I really only needed to look at include directives for now I was hopping for a lightweight solution. I'm basically just making a simple makefile generator like bakefile or countless others

Comment: @nickeb96 - A generator that has to be checked by hand for accuracy, is of no use at all.

Comment: @sln The whole point in parsing all of the source files is so it doesn't have to be checked by hand.

Answer (score 45):

Your instinct on using regex is correct.

```
import re
re.split('[^a-zA-Z]', string_to_split)
```

The `[^a-zA-Z]` part means "not alphabetic characters".

Comment: This answer is dangerous because it doesn't split by whitespace.

Comment: It splits on space for me.  It seems like it  would split on anything except alpha characters.  It only excludes a-z and A-Z - so it's a very limited set.

Comment: why not simply `re.split('\W', string_to_split)` (or, if you want to exclude whitespace also, `re.split('\W+', string_to_split)`)?

Comment: `\W` will split on numbers and the underscore as well as non-alpha characters.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 12):

The two options mentioned by others that are best in my opinion are `re.split` and `re.findall`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'\W+', '#include "header.hpp"')
['', 'include', 'header', 'hpp', '']
>>> re.findall(r'\w+', '#include "header.hpp"')
['include', 'header', 'hpp']
```

A quick benchmark:

```
>>> setup = "import re; word_pattern = re.compile(r'\w+'); sep_pattern = re.compile(r'\W+')"
>>> iterations = 10**6
>>> timeit.timeit("re.findall(r'\w+', '#header foo bar!')", setup=setup, number=iterations)
3.000092029571533
>>> timeit.timeit("word_pattern.findall('#header foo bar!')", setup=setup, number=iterations)
1.5247418880462646
>>> timeit.timeit("re.split(r'\W+', '#header foo bar!')", setup=setup, number=iterations)
3.786440134048462
>>> timeit.timeit("sep_pattern.split('#header foo bar!')", setup=setup, number=iterations)
2.256173849105835
```

The functional difference is that `re.split` keeps empty tokens. That’s usually not useful for tokenization purposes, but the following should be identical to the `re.findall` solution:

```
>>> filter(bool, re.split(r'\W+', '#include "header.hpp"'))
['include', 'header', 'hpp']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
s = 'foo bar- blah/hm.lala'
print(re.findall(r"\w+",s))
```

**output : ['foo', 'bar', 'blah', 'hm', 'lala']**

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex. The `\W` token will match all non-word characters (which is about the same as non-alphanumeric).  Word characters are `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, and `_`.  If you want to match underscores as well you could just do `[\W_]`.

```
>>> import re
>>> line = '#   include"header.hpp"  ' 
>>> m = re.match(r'^\s*#\s*include\W+([\w\.]+)\W*$', line)
>>> m.group(1)
'header.hpp'
```

Comment: The only problem with this is if I replace include with something like define I get a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' so I would need a way to tell if it is an include directive before I execute this code

Comment: Most C parsers don't allow newline between the  `#` and `include` where this `*#\s*include` would allow it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
re.split('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', string_to_split)
```

for all !(alphanumaric) characters

Comment: hey, can you explain what it does?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
import re

test_str = '    #   include "header.hpp"'

match = re.match(r'\s*#\s*include\s*("[\w.]*")', test_str)
if match:
    print match.group(1)
```

Comment: The only problem with this is if I replace include with something like define I get a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: replace in the regular expression or the input string?  why not just to see if a match is found first...

Comment: ah it works now with the if statement. If only stack overflow would let me accept 2 answers.

Answer (score 0):

While not exact, most parse header directives like this

`(?m)^\h*#\h*include\h*["<](\w[\w.]*)\h*[">]`

Where, (?m) is multi-line mode, \h is horizontal whitespace (aka [^\S\r\n] ).